# Find complex numbers to form a square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The affixes of the complex numbers $a = 3 + i$ and $b = 1 + 2i$ are $A$ and $B$. Fidn the complex numbers $p,p^\prime, q, q^\prime$ with affixes $P, P^\prime, Q, Q^\prime$ such that $ABQP$ and $ABQ^\prime P^\prime$ are square.

$AB = b - a = -2 + i$

$AP = i(-2 +i) = -1 + -2i$ and $AP^\prime = -i(-2 + i) = 1 + 2i$

$p = a + (-1  -2 i) = 1 + 2i$

$p^\prime = 2- i$

Similarly $q = 0$ and $q^\prime = 2 + 4i$.

I did not understand why $AB = b- a$, in my opinion it should be $|b -a|$. No ?

Comment: Think of $AB$ as the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{OB}-\overrightarrow{OA}=b-a\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on the Gauss plain we have:

$A(3,1)$, $B(1,2)$ and $\vec{AB}(1-3,2-1)=\vec{AB}(-2,1)$.

By the way, $|\vec{AB}|=|a-b|=|b-a|$.